# Large CSV download script timing out

Tags: php, csv

I have a a script that can upload the contents of a CSV file and download the links to a local directory, the CSV file i need to upload to it is about 4056 lines long and 4056 FTP downloads, the script works fine but the web server times out when i use it.

even tried set_time_limit(0);

is there a way i could session the script and loop the process so it could do it's job for a few hours without interruptions.

```
<?php  
/**
* Please change your upload directory according to your needs. Make sure you include the trailing slash!
*
* Windows    C:\tmp\
* Linux      /tmp/
*/
$uploaddir = '/tmp/';

if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){

    // Read uploaded file
    $lines  = file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    echo "Reading file ... <br/>";
    $linecount = 0;
    foreach($lines  as $line ){
        echo ++$linecount . ". FTP Url is : " .$line . "<br/>";
        echo "   Downloading " . $line . "<br/>";
        $parsed_url_values = parse_url($line);
        //TODO perhaps do a validation of the ftp url??

        if($parsed_url_values['scheme'] == 'ftp'){
                // set up basic connection
                $conn_id = ftp_connect($parsed_url_values['host']);

                // login with username and password
                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $parsed_url_values['user'], $parsed_url_values['pass']);
                ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
                $path = rtrim($parsed_url_values['path'], '_');
                $filename = basename($path);

                if (ftp_get($conn_id, $uploaddir . $filename, $path , FTP_BINARY)) {
                        echo "   Successfully downloaded the file " .$line . "<br/>";
                } else {
                        echo "   Could not save the file to " . $line . ". Please verify the url is correct and the file exists.<br/>";
                }
        } else {
                echo "   Sorry. This script was made for FTP downloads only.";
        }
    }
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
  Select the file to upload : <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the execution time of your script by using `max_execution_time`. You can use this example, place it on top of your script:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
.. The rest of your script
```

Hope this will help  you!

Comment: let me give it a go

Comment: Still getting 500 error, starting to think i mite need to alter this and set it as a cron job unless i can find a way to loop it. i got ubuntu running on a VM and got that running but that is still double handling and seems to be really slow too.

Comment: nope just 500 error the script works fine, i just split the csv and it can't even do 100 lines in 1 sitting. im running out time to get these image files for my retail site, my wholesaler just had to change from http to ftp to get the files

Comment: nope this failed and running this via cron got permission denied

Answer (score 0):

In my practice I often use step by step loading if i can't load data via cron or php cli.

Something like that (not tested):

```
<?php
$newFileName = '/path/to/file.csv';
$line = isset($_REQUEST['csvline']) ? (int) $_REQUEST['csvline'] : 0;
$handle = fopen($newFileName, "r");

//10 seconds for each step
$stepTime = 10;
$startTime = time();
$lineCounter = 0;
while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
{
    //already loaded lines
    $lineCounter++;
    if ($lineCounter <= $line) continue;
    //here goes your script logic
    //stops when time goes out
    if (time() - $startTime >= $stepTime) break;
}
//next you need to query this script again 
//using js maybe (window.location or ajax call)
//so you can see loading progress or any other useful information
//like
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "<script>window.location = '/your.php?csvline={$lineCounter}'<script>";
}
//you even can start loading from last line before script fails
```

But i'm sure that using cron is the best solution for your problem.